# How to return a read-only IEnumerable<T> instead of a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable

i wanted to integrate ienumerable in my code so that it is readonly but i don't know where to possibly implement it. So far i haven't found any solution in the internet that might answer my problem. As of now, i have only used List and wanted to integrate ienumerable in my code. Also, feel free to suggest anything if you notice bad coding practices.

Here is the code:

```
public static List<GuitarItems> GetGuitarItems(string itemCategory)
{
    List<GuitarItems> list = new List<GuitarItems>();
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM guitarItems WHERE brand LIKE @brand");

    try
    {
        conn1.Open();
        command1.CommandText = query;
        command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("brand", itemCategory));
        SqlDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string type = reader.GetString(1);
            string brand = reader.GetString(2);
            string model = reader.GetString(3);
            double price = reader.GetDouble(4);
            string itemimage1 = reader.GetString(5);
            string itemimage2 = reader.GetString(6);
            string description = reader.GetString(7);
            string necktype = reader.GetString(8);
            string body = reader.GetString(9);
            string fretboard = reader.GetString(10);
            string fret = reader.GetString(11);
            string bridge = reader.GetString(12);
            string neckpickup = reader.GetString(13);
            string bridgepickup = reader.GetString(14);
            string hardwarecolor = reader.GetString(15);

            GuitarItems gItems = new GuitarItems(id, type, brand, model, price, itemimage1, itemimage2, description, necktype, body,
                fretboard, fret, bridge, neckpickup, bridgepickup, hardwarecolor);
            list.Add(gItems);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn1.Close();
        command1.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    return list;
}
```

And then here is another code:

```
private void FillPage()
{
    List<GuitarItems> itemList = new List<GuitarItems>();
    List<string> itemListPage = new List<string>();

    itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems(brandType);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (GuitarItems gList in itemList)
    {
        itemListPage.Add("GuitarItemsIbanezDetails" + (x + 1) + ".aspx");

        sb.Append(
                string.Format(
                    @"
                    <div class='one-two'>
                        <a href='{3}' runat="'server'"><img runat="'server'" src='{0}'/></a>
                        <div class='content'>
                            <div id='label'>{1} {2}</div>
                        </div>

                </div>", gList.ItemImage1, gList.Brand, gList.Model, itemListPage[x]));

        x++;

    }


    lblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();

}
```

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.  And you can't build server-side controls like that.  You should use data-binding.

Comment: @SLaks - what if i add a code that will cancel out the user's input if there are script tags? will that help eliminate XSS vulnerability?

Comment: No.  You need to learn about _encoding_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically a `List<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`, but I understand what you mean. If you return a `List<T>` then that list may be modified. You want to return something that can get passed around without anyone modifying its contents.

There are two things you can do to achieve this. The first may be all you need.

First, change this

```
public static List<GuitarItems> GetGuitarItems(string itemCategory)
```

to this:

```
public static IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems> GetGuitarItems(string itemCategory)
```

If you do that and nothing else, the return value of the function will be cast as `IReadOnlyList<T>`. That interface doesn't allow modification of the list. (It doesn't prevent altering the properties of items in the list - that's an entirely separate matter.)

`List<T>` can be cast as `IReadOnlyList<T>` so you don't have to change anything else inside your method. You can create a `List<GuitarItems>` just as you are now, but return it as an `IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems>` just by changing the return type of the function.

That probably accomplishes what you need. However, if you're especially concerned about something else modifying the contents of that list you can go further.

For example, even though the item returned from the collection is cast as `IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems>`, someone could still do this:

```
var readonlyList = GetGuitarItems("category"); // returns IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems>
var list = readonlyList as List<GuitarItems>;
list.Clear(); // Oh, no - they've modified the list anyway!
```

This will work because the item returned from the function is actually a List. No one should try to cast it as something else - they should use the type you're returning. But for some odd reason someone could do that.

For extra prevention you could change the return of your function from this:

```
return list;
```

To this:

```
return list.AsReadOnly();
```

The result is that now you're not returning a `List<GuitarItems>` cast as `IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems>`. `AsReadOnly()` creates a new collection, a `ReadOnlyCollection<GuitarItems>` and casts *that* as `IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems>`. Now not only does the type getting returned indicate that the list can't be modified, but it really can't be modified because it's a read-only collection.

A good way to look at it is that the return value of the method should indicate what you expect consumers to do with it. If you want them to receive a list that they shouldn't modify then return an `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

---

A related question is whether you should return an `IEnumerable<T>` or an `IReadOnlyList<T>`. `IEnumerable<T>` is more general and also does not represent a list that can be changed. You'll see it used far more often. The difference is that an `IEnumerable<T>` could represent a query that gets executed. If the items to be enumerated get enumerated more than once then it could result in executing the query more than once.

In your example above, if you changed `List<GuitarItems>` to `IEnumerable<GuitarItems>` you're still really returning a `List<GuitarItems>`, so enumerating that list multiple times *does not* execute a query repeatedly. But the consumer who now has an `IEnumerable<GuitarItems>` can't know that, so they'll want to do something like this:

```
var items = GetGuitarItems("category").ToList();
```

to make sure that the query is executed once and put into a list that they can enumerate as many times as they want to.

Returning `IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems>` lets them know that what they have is definitely a list, not something that's going to get queried each time it's enumerated.

This becomes apparent if you use Resharper. If you have an `IEnumerable<T>` and you enumerate it more than once it will warn you. The item might really be a list or array but you can't know that.

Comment: By the way, i have a question..in the second code that i have provided above in private void FillPage() method. In order to make it work using your solution, I changed the List<GuitarItems> itemList = new List<GuitarItems>(); into IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems> itemList;. Have i done it correctly? because it seems to be not working if i try to do it like this ->IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems> itemList = new IReadOnlyList<GuitarItems>();

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve?

`List<T>` it is already an `IEnumerable<T>` because it implements `IEnumerable<T>` interface so you can treat your `List<T>` like `IEnumerable<T>` for example in methods arguments.